# Trying to change pointer value

Tags: c, pointers, memory, shortcode

I was making a test with pointers in C, and when I tried this code:

```
int main()
{

    char  * b = "abc";
    char * c = b;

    *c = *(b+1); //problem
    printf("%s",c); 
}
```

I got a mistake on the commented line, what I was specting to print was bbc , why that pointer assignment isn't working?

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to modify a string literal.

Comment: @BlueMoon the accepted answer to the dup is actually pretty bad, too bad the OP did not accept Keith's answer, which you have to scroll down to find.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The question *is* dup and there *are* good, accurate answers in that page. That's all I care when I vote to close. What OP accepts is not something I/anyone can influence.

Comment: @BlueMoon there were perhaps better dups to choose from it seems like few users care about the quality of the dups they choose. Regardless I urged the OP to accept Keith's answer since it is clearly a better answer, so hopefully that will be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

`c` is pointing to a string literal, you are not allowed to modify string literals, it is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This is covered in the draft C99 standard section `6.4.5` *String literals* paragraph *6* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined**.

So the behavior of this program is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Variables `b` and `c` are both pointing to the same string, which is located in the (read-only) code section of the program.

During run-time, when the CPU executes `*c = *(b+1)`, it performs an illegal memory access.

You should declare this string as a local array in function `main`, so it will be located in the stack instead:

```
char b[] = "abc";
```